# mongodb and geospatial schema

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

im breaking my head with mongo and geospatial,
so maybe someone has some idea or solution how to solve this:
my object schema is like this sample for geoJSON taken from http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html.

```
{
"name":"name",
"geoJSON":{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[100,0],[101,0],[101,1],[100,1],[100,0]]]},"properties":{}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[100,0],[101,0],[101,1],[100,1],[100,0]]]},"properties":{}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[100,0],[101,0],[101,1],[100,1],[100,0]]]},"properties":{}}
]}}
```

additional info: I'm using spring data but that shouldn't influence the answer.
main problem is how/where to put indexes in this schema. I need to make a query to find all documents for given Point if some polygon intersects.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating a 2d or 2dsphere index on `geoJSON.features.geometry` you should be able to create an index covering all of the geoJSON-objects.

To get all documents where at least one of the sub-object in the `features` array covers a certain point, you can use the [`$geoIntersects`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#op._S_geoIntersects) operator with a geoJSON Point:

```
db.yourcollection.find( 
            { `geoJSON.features.geometry` :
              { $geoIntersects :
                { $geometry :
                  { type : "Point" ,
                    coordinates: [ 100.5 , 0.5 ] 
                  } 
                } 
              } 
            } 
          )
```

Comment: if this help, I'll buy you a beer.

Comment: by adding index like this: db.<collection>.ensureIndex( { "geoJSON.features.geometry" : "2dsphere" }) and using this query: db.<collection>.find({"geoJSON.features.geometry":{$geoIntersects:{$geometry :{type:"Point",coordinates:[100,0]}}}})